# glDrawElement, why does it cause the program to stop working?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am getting frustrated about this. I am trying to render a cube with Vertex Buffer Objects and I was learning about Projection so I am trying to make a frame of a cube. However, this code does not work. When I run the program on Code::Blocks, the program stops working.

[image: Program stops working]

I tried to find out the reason by commenting out the content of the render() method, and then the program doesn't stop working. So this line of code

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_index->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // render the cube
```

may be the source of the problem. But I don't know how to fix this, because this is just what I usually do (I have made similar programs and they worked)

I really really appreciate your help!

```
ProjectionCube::ProjectionCube()
{
    rotationAngle = 0.0;
}

bool ProjectionCube::initialize()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
#else
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glBufferData");
#endif

    if (!glGenBuffers || !glBindBuffer || !glBufferData)
    {
        std::cerr << "VBOs are not supported by your graphics card" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    initializeVertexBuffers();

    // bind vertex buffer and index buffer
    // set vertex pointer to the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); 

    // no color buffer to bind
    return true;
}

void ProjectionCube::initializeVertexBuffers()
{
    const float size = 0.5f;
    m_vertex = getCubeVertices(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_vertex->size(); i++) {
        std::cout << m_vertex->at(i) << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    static const unsigned int index[] = {//using triangles to render
                                  0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, //bottom
                                  0, 4, 5, 0, 1, 5, //back
                                  0, 4, 7, 0, 3, 7, //left
                                  1, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, //right
                                  4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 6, //top
                                  2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 7}; // front

    m_index = new vector<unsigned int>(index, index + sizeof(index) / sizeof(index[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < m_index->size(); i++) {
        std::cout << m_index->at(i) << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbos[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * m_vertex->size(),
                 &m_vertex->at(0), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbos[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbos[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * m_index->size(),
                 &m_index->at(0), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void ProjectionCube::render(float m_x, float m_y, float m_z)
{
   glTranslatef(m_x, m_y, m_z); // move to where the cube is located
    //glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_index->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // render the cube
}

void ProjectionCube::animate(float dt)
{
    const float SPEED = 15.0f;
    rotationAngle += SPEED * dt;

    if (rotationAngle >= 360 || rotationAngle <= 0) {
        rotationAngle = -rotationAngle;
    }
}

vector<GLfloat>* ProjectionCube::getCubeVertices(float r)
{
    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {//bottom square
                                       -r, -r, -r,
                                       r, -r, -r,
                                       r, -r, r,
                                       -r, -r, r,
                                       //top square
                                       -r, r, -r,
                                       r, r, -r,
                                       r, r, r,
                                       -r, r, r,};
    vector<GLfloat>* result = new vector<GLfloat>(vertices, vertices + sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: at first glance, I can only see, that you activated the color array and did not bind a buffer to it. But I don't actually think this should cause your program to crash. You should check for GLErrors in your code to make sure, everything works fine and your buffers are correctly bound

Comment: Thank you! I will for sure check the glErrors

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't post when `render` is called, all I can do is advise you into not using `new vector`.  There is no need for it as far as I can see.

Since your error occurs when you use `m_index` in the `render` function, and assuming `m_index` is a pointer to a vector, then there is no need for it to be a pointer (assuming it's a member variable of `ProjectionCube`).

There are two issues with `new vector`.  Why does your program dynamically allocate a in the `getCubeVertices` function?  The following removes the dynamic allocation:

```
vector<GLfloat> ProjectionCube::getCubeVertices(float r)
{
    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {//bottom square
                                       -r, -r, -r,
                                       r, -r, -r,
                                       r, -r, r,
                                       -r, -r, r,
                                       //top square
                                       -r, r, -r,
                                       r, r, -r,
                                       r, r, r,
                                       -r, r, r,};
   return vector<GLfloat>(vertices, vertices + sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));
}
```

Then in `InitializeVertexBuffers()`, the `m_vertex` member variable is no longer a pointer, but an object:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> m_vertex;  // assuming these are member variables in your class
std::vector<unsigned int> m_index;
//...
void ProjectionCube::initializeVertexBuffers()
{
    const float size = 0.5f;
    m_vertex = getCubeVertices(size);
    //...
    m_index = vector<unsigned int>(index, index + sizeof(index) / sizeof(index[0]));
```

Again, no need for `new vector`.  You now use `m_index.` and `m_vertex.`.

Now what does this buy you, as opposed to what you were doing before?  Well, now you're guaranteed that `m_index` is valid when `render` is called.   There is no way for `m_index` to have been deallocated, or the pointer corrupted, etc. since `m_index` is no longer a pointer.

You also rid yourself of a potential memory leak using the above approach.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Yet the program just crashes at the line of glDrawElements(). It does not even execute lines after that. Have you encountered similar situations?

Comment: According to this link: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml  your indices (last parameter) cannot be NULL (note:  I do not use OpenGL).  Probably what is happening is that the glDrawElements is attempting to read starting from address 0, thus causing the issue (attempting to read from an invalid address)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: When an index buffer is bound, the last argument of `glDrawElements()` is a relative offset into the buffer. So it's completely correct and very common for it to be 0.

Comment: Really don't know why, but I rewrote the thing again blindly, and it worked this time!